# Multiple Audio files on HTML page, need for only one to play at a time

Tags: javascript

I have multiple audio files that play when clicked using the following javascript code:

function playSound(el,soundfile) {

```
          if (el.mp3) {
              if(el.mp3.paused) el.mp3.play();
              else el.mp3.pause();
          } else {
              el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
              el.mp3.play();
          }
      }
```

The problem is that when two are clicked both audio files will play simultaneously.  I need for the first audio file to stop playing when the second is clicked.

What do I need to add to this code.

Comment: What you could do, is make a global array called 'audioElements' for example, place the element in there when you play the sound. To pause all others, just loop over the array and pause them.

Comment: can you assist with the code

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the sound API from HTML5 yet, so this is just to get my point across.

So, Like I said in my comment, you could add all elements to a global array and pause them like that.

```
  var audio = [];

  function playSound(el,soundfile) {

    // Pause all 

     if (el.mp3) {
          if(el.mp3.paused) {
              // Pause all sounds
              pauseAllSounds();

              el.mp3.play();

              // Add the sound to the audio array
              audio.push(el);

              // You should probably clean up the audio array too, 
              // so no two identical audio files exists in the array, 
              // but that's up to you! :)
          }
          else el.mp3.pause();
      } else {
          el.mp3 = new Audio(soundfile);
          el.mp3.play();
      }
  }

  function pauseAllSounds(){
    audio.forEach(function(el){
       if(!el.mp3.paused) el.mp3.pause();
    });
  }
```

Comment: So, all I do now is add the audio files in the array, kind of like:   var audio = [ sound1.mp3, sound2.mp3];

Comment: Yes, but not the names of the files.. But rather the 'reference' to the element, just like you passed the element to the 'playSound' function before.

Comment: I'm a bit confused

Comment: The HMTL in the document looks like this:

<span div="2" class="error_sound" onclick="playSound(this,'sounds/activity_1/letter_m_a_1_correct_v2.mp3');">
     <img src="../../images/rainforest/letter_m/activity_1/a1_monkey.png" width="324px" height="274px" alt="Monkey" onclick="showPanelGroup_2();" />
    </span>
    

    <span div="3" class="error_sound" onclick="playSound(this,'sounds/activity_1/letter_m_a_1_incorrect_b.mp3');">
     <img src="../../images/rainforest/letter_m/activity_1/a1_butterfly.png" width="324px" height="274px" alt="Butterfly" />
    </span>